# Google OAuth redirect_uri_missmatch

Tags: google-oauth, cypress

I am trying to create an automated login in my own API through Cypress.
It uses Google SSO and with the authorization code, it generates an entirely new JWT to the user.

Everything looks fine. I can retrieve an id_token and access_token from https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token using the refresh_token

And with this data I can even check the user consuming the route https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo

But when I pass my auth code to the API it says `redirect_uri_mismatch`
I am calling an URL like

> `localhost:3000/foo/auth/callback?state=%7B%22pasUrl%22:%22terminal%22%7D&code=4/0AX4XfWhZRB1mZZ_VByR26EGJkXlhO1WMQ89yaysG56ihdlb9dJbOASvITFm-yv6iMMGYrA&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20openid&authuser=0&hd=foo.com&prompt=consent`

and in the list of Authorized redirct URIs I have `http://localhost:3000/foo/auth/callback`

Comment: Please edit your question and post a screen shot of the consent screen error message you are getting.   redirect_uri_mismatch  ...... What ...  btw im not sure some of your scopes are even valid why are you adding all of those?

Comment: This may help [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

Comment: @DaImTo I am using https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client, hence I don't know how to reach the consent screen. Can you help me with this?

Comment: is this a web app? or are you running this on the machine itself?

Comment: @DaImTo I am running locally this, both API and the application. The login is running through cypress requests, not through the browser.

Comment: Adding more. I am sending a request to the API, which then uses the GoogleAPI in node, calling the `getToken` function.

Comment: The consent screen must be opened in a web browser.

Comment: @DaImTo I was able to move a little further by adding in the API the redirect_url to "postmessage" but now I am having unauthorized_client, even though the keys match

Comment: The code expires in under five minutes sure your responding fast enough?